# jquery anchor click not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Can anyone see why the alert is not working?

```
<table class="result-table  pending-accept">
    <thead class="bottom-align">
        <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Source</th>
            <th>Last Transmitted</th>
            <th>Last Staged</th>            
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var trans in processItems)
        { 
            <tr>
                <td class="autosize"><div>@trans.Code</div></td>
                <td class="autosize"><div>@trans.Description</div></td>
                <td class="autosize"><div>@(trans.HasBeenLoadedToVault ? trans.VaultLoadDt.ToString() : "")</div></td>
                <td class="autosize"><div>@trans.StageLoadDt</div></td> @*                 <td class="autosize"><div><a href="@Url.Action("Accept", new { id = trans.Id,loadSource = trans.LoadSource})" class="button grid-sized">Accept</a></div></td>*@
                <td class="autosize"><div><a href="#" data-id="@trans.Id" data-loadSource="@trans.LoadSource" class="button grid-sized acceptButton">Accept</a></div></td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>



<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {



            $(".pending-accept a").live('click',function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                alert('Clicked!');
                return false;

            });



    });

</script>
```

---

EDIT   This Worked

```
        $(document).on('click', '.pending-accept a', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('Clicked!');
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer not an edit to the question.

Comment: if that had worked it's because the content was appending before, info was quite of hard to detect, base on your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The live function in jQuery is deprecated : http://api.jquery.com/live/.
Instead of using the live() function, use on().

Answer (score 0):

After version 1.7, `.live()` has been deprecated..

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is a deprecation issue. From what I can see, there's no element's with the class `pending-accept` that have any `a` element children, thus why your selector `.pending-accept a` is failing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest version of jQuery, or any version equal or greater to 1.7, use on() instead of live() for your alert box to function properly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".pending-accept a").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Clicked!');
        return false;
  });
});
</script>
```